# Xenko: The local source 'C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Xenko\NugetDev doesn't exist

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net-core, nuget

I've installed Xenko before to try out game development. But after trying out, I've chosen to stick to creating apps. So I uninstalled Xenko and removed all Xenko-related folders even in the AppData directory.

But whenever I try to install nuget packages, it seems like it is related to Xenko now.

```
GET https://packages.xenko.com/nuget/FindPackagesById()?id='Newtonsoft.Json'&semVerLevel=2.0.0
error: The local source 'C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Xenko\NugetDev' doesn't exist.
```

I've tried to repair Visual Studio, repair my .NET Core installations, and it doesn't work.

Comment: Hi reiniellematt, do you see the source `C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Xenko\NugetDev` which in `Tools=>Nuget Package Manager=>Package Manager Settings=>Package Source`, can the workaround work? Or you can create same directory the error message indicates, though empty folder is enough. Please let me know if it helps:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> According to your error message, you set
>   `C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Xenko\NugetDev` as one of the Package
>   Sources.

**Suggestion:**

First of all, to avoid something from Xenko rest corrupt the package-install process, make sure you've uninstalled the extension.

It seems that you uninstalled the `Xenko application`, but as I know, when you install the Xenko, it will install corresponding `Xenko extension` to `Visual Studio`.And the extension may corrupt your normal use after you've uninstalled `Xenko application`. See this [similar issue](https://github.com/xenko3d/xenko/issues/215#issuecomment-424315651).

So please **uninstall that extension in VS as well**. Click `Uninstall` button and close all VS instance, then the modification will begin.

For VS2017, go `Tools=>Extensions and Updates` to find it and for VS2019, go `Extensions=>Manage Extensions` to find it.

**Workaround:**

I think this issue has something to do with nuget `Package Manager Settings` option. Go `Tools=>Nuget Package Manager=>Package Manager Settings=>Package Source`. I assume you once set some Xenko-related Url or path as package source.

When you try to install nuget package in VS. If there exists **invalid** package source in it, it will throw errors like `local source ... not exist`.

So you may have package source settings similar to this:

[image]

And the path `C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Xenko\NugetDev` actually doesn't exist in machine, which causes the error like what you got.

The easily way to resolve it is to **delete** the blue-highlight package source which is invalid in your machine with the **red delete button** and choose **OK button**.

Hope it helps.